# Typescript TypeGuard not working on class properties

Tags: typescript

I think title and example code says all:

```
private x: IJobOverview | IJobRecursive;
method1()
{
    const o = this.x;
    if (isJobOverview(this.x))
        this.x;                   //o is IJobOverview or IJobRecursive !!WHY?
    if (isJobOverview(o))
        o;                        //o is IJobOverview
}
```

Is this bug? Did I do something wrong?
My Typescript version is 2.2.

**Updated:**

I get error:

> (74,61): error TS2339: Property 'tagIds' does not exist on type
>   'IJobOverview | IJobRecursive'

.

Extended code:

```
if (isJobOverview(this.x))
  this.x.tagIds;               //line 47
```

I compile with WebPack ([Javascript services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices))

Comment: In both cases the variable is of type `IJobOverview`, at least in playground.

Comment: In order to help you, we need to see the implementation of isJobOverview and the 2 interfaces IJobOverview and IJobrecursive